# Problem clicking an element with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click an element on a web page using selenium and python

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("market-selection.ng-scope").click()
```

But I get the error that the element isn't clickable

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

This is the element html (it's not in a frame btw); I'm guessing that the interactable part is the second div but I also tried the other two just in case...

```
<div class="market-selection-container 18" ng-repeat="market in wrapperCategoryGroup.currentMacroCategoria.mkl track by $index">
      <!-- ngIf: wrapperCategoryGroup.marketTypes[market].nm    -->
      <div class="market-selection ng-scope" ng-if="wrapperCategoryGroup.marketTypes[market].nm" ng-class="{'active':wrapperCategoryGroup.currentMarketType == market}" ng-click="wrapperCategoryGroup.getMarketType(market)" style="">
        <span class="ng-binding">
          doppia chance 
        </span>
      </div>
    <!-- end ngIf: wrapperCategoryGroup.marketTypes[market].nm -->
 </div>
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **save** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.market-selection.ng-scope > span.ng-binding").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='market-selection ng-scope']/span[@class='ng-binding' and contains(., 'doppia chance')]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.market-selection.ng-scope > span.ng-binding"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='market-selection ng-scope']/span[@class='ng-binding' and contains(., 'doppia chance')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: it still returns that error (by the way I had it implicitly waitin before clicking, will it still work?)

Comment: @Grinch Remove the implicit way totally. Mixing up both of them results in unpredictable waits.

Comment: But I also realized that <div class="market-selection ng-scope active"... is when it is clicked, otherwise it's <div class="market-selection ng-scope" ... but even changing the path it won't work

Comment: Even if I didn't have WebDriverWait? I only used implicitly wait

Comment: @Grinch Updated answer removing `active` from the value of _class_. Retest and let me know the result.

Comment: still same error... would it help if I posted my entire code? Maybe I'm doing some other mistake

Comment: The HTML is crucial, did you pick up the HTML before clicking?

Comment: Ok it worked out, I didn't properly test your xpath solution AFTER removing "active". Thank you